# Name of the custom web framework or CMS built specifically for "Coming Soon" landing pages

Tags: email, frameworks, content-management-system

It seems like I remember seeing a web framework specifically for the Coming Soon pages that let you enter your email address to be notified about updates. Anybody know the name of that project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are several plugins like that for Wordpress: you may be thinking of this one..

http://www.cssjockey.com/wordpress-plugins/custom-coming-soon-pages-wordpress-plugin